# Clone a div with new ids and event handlers in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div, I want a new copy of div to be added somewhere in the page, but with new ids and  new event handlers. New ids can be in the form "original id + _cloned". I am able to provide new ids, but I want all the event handlers which were there in original div, to be attached to new div which is mapped to new ids. Is there any way to do that using jQuery?

Comment: You can use `.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents]` to copy the event handlers and data.. however I doubt if delegated events which are bound by ID would still work on cloned element. ex: `$(document).on('click'. '#someId', function () { });` will not work after you clone `#someId` and change it to `#someId_cloned`

Comment: Why not just map these delegated events to a class that both the original and cloned items will have? That way when you do the deep clone everything still works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents]` to copy the event handlers and data..

However I doubt if delegated events which are bound by ID would still work on cloned element.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sfrm9/

`$(document).on('click'. '#someId', function () { });` - would not work after you clone `#someId` and change it to `#someId_cloned`

As mcpDESIGNS mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302116/clone-a-div-with-new-ids-and-event-handlers-in-jquery/12302204#comment16505538_12302116), you should map it to use `class` instead of id for the delegated handlers and then your clone should just work work fine.

**Ex:**

```
<div id="#someId" class="someClass" >Test</div>
```

**JS:**

`$(document).on('click'. '.someClass', function () { });`

instead of

`$(document).on('click'. '#someId', function () { });`

Comment: yes, that is the issue, my changes are getting reflected on original div. So I want to know that is there any way to have new set of event listners which listens to new ids?

Comment: @user1367714 Check out **mcpDESIGNS** [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302116/clone-a-div-with-new-ids-and-event-handlers-in-jquery/12302204#comment16505538_12302116)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the jQuery documentation for the [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function, you'll see that there are two optional parameters to include data and event handlers for the element itself and for the elements descendants when cloning.

That will handle preserving the event handlers (as long as they're bound directly to that element, rather than being delegated), then you'll simply need to modify the `id` property of the resulting element. The following should do what you need:

```
$('#myid').clone(true).prop('id', function(i, oldId) {
    return oldId + '_cloned';
});
```

Comment: yes, that is correct, but by this when I make changes in cloned div, the changes get reflected in original div. So I need a separate copy of event handlers.

Comment: @user1367714 I haven't done much cloning of elements myself, but that's not how I'd expect it to work. What kinds of changes are you making to the elements, and what event handlers are attached to the original element? If you're using static IDs, for example, then they won't be modified when copying the event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

```
.clone(true);
```

this way event handlers should be copied along with the elements

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the events using a class for the divs. Then you can leave the same class to all divs that you need to respond to that event.

If your event is binded using an id selector, it will not work on your new div because you have to change its id, but it should work with classes.